# dtracing a short lived application

Tags: c, dtrace

I have written a DTrace script which measures the time spent inside a function in my C program. The program itself runs, outputs some data and then exits.

The problem is that it finishes way to fast for me to get the process id and start DTrace.

At the moment I have a sleep() statement inside my code which gives me enough time to start DTrace. Having to modify your code in order to get information on it kinda defeats the purpose of Dtrace... right.

Basically what I'm after is to make DTrace wait for a process id to show up and then run my script against it.

Comment: I'm not a expert, but `dtruss` may be useful for you.

Comment: @arrowdodger As far as I can tell, dtruss allows you to print info on process system calls, which is not really what I'm after. Basically the problem is that my program finishes way to fast for me to get the process id and start DTrace. I have modified my question to make it more clear.

Comment: For some weird reason I cannot answer my own question, so I'm posting it here. The solution is very simple, in the DTrace script change the pid provider to "pid$target" and then from the command line use "dtrace -s myscript.d -c ./myProg myFuncToAnalyse".

Answer (score 5):

Presumably you're using the pid provider, in which case there's no way to enable those probes before the process has been created. The usual solution to this is to invoke the program from dtrace itself with its "-c" option.

If for some reason you can't do that (i.e. your process has to be started in some environment set up by some other process), you can try a more complex approach: use proc:::start or proc:::exec-success to trace when your program is actually started, use the stop() action to stop the program at that point, and then use system() to run another DTrace invocation that uses the pid provider, and then "prun" the program again.